# Finding specific tags in an HTML with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the text inside the tag "Title" in the HTML below. By calling soup and find_all:

```
soup.find_all(attrs={"class": 'flaggenrahmen'})
```

My output is:

```
[<img alt="Germany" class="flaggenrahmen" src="https://tmssl.akamaized.net/images/flagge/verysmall/40.png?lm=1520612525" title="Germany"/>]
```

How could i extract the word "Germany" from title or alt?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access an attribute from an HTML tag with BeautifulSoup you can simply do `tag['attribute']`. So, in your case you should first, get the `Tag` object outside of the list provided by `soup.find_all`:

```
tags = soup.find_all(attrs={"class": 'flaggenrahmen'})
wanted_word = tags[0]['alt'] # or, alternatively, tags[0]['title']
```

If your tag is unique, you could use, instead:

```
wanted_word = soup.find(attrs={"class": 'flaggenrahmen'})['alt']
```

Or, if you need multiple results, use a list comprehension:

```
tags = soup.find_all(attrs={"class": 'flaggenrahmen'})
wanted_words = [tag['alt'] for tag in tags]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use find command like this:

```
soup.find(text="Germany")
```

also i recomend you look at the documentation  and examples here:
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

```
doc = BeautifulSoup("<document><content/>INSERT FOOTER HERE</document", "xml")
footer = BeautifulSoup("<footer>Here's the footer</footer>", "xml")
doc.find(text="INSERT FOOTER HERE").replace_with(footer)
# 'INSERT FOOTER HERE'
print(doc)
# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
# <document><content/><footer>Here's the footer</footer></document>
```

Comment: I don't think this was the OP's question, the OP already found the correct tag, now they have to extract the text "Germany" from it.